# Azure profiler doesn't show performance traces in app insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I got a .net 6 service which is running in a local cluster on my machine. I also got an application insight which was linked to a storage account. The service writes to app insight using nlog and I do see log traces in app insight.

I tried using the Azure profiler to test performance of the service. What I was doing to enable the profiler was:

1. install package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.AspNetCore (with latest version 2.5.3-beta1)
2. in my stratup file added these lines:

   services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
   services.AddServiceProfiler();

I then ran a request to the service. I waited a few minutes and tried checking the performance tab in app insight. In that tab I do see the requests I've made and their average duration, but in the "drill into..." section, there is no button of "Profiler traces" and in the profiler section of the performance there's only a message

> "No application has reported a profiling session. Try use 'Profile now' to trigger one."

What am I missing to trigger a profiler session? What is this "Profile now" button?